# How to derive the shapes of tensors given the networks architecture, number of outputs and number of samples

Tags: tensorflow

How can we calculate the shapes of various tensors involved in the computation graph once we know the network architecture (number of hidden layers, number of units in each layer), number of outputs, number of inputs and number of samples in the training set. (Assuming the network is fully connected).

For example, lets say there are 100 features, 10000 samples, 2 hidden layers (H0, H1) and 10 outputs. H1 has 500 units and H2 has 5000 units. Assume RELU activation is used in H0/H1 and softmax is used for output layer.

In this case, although the sequence of calculations that need to happen is very clear, finding correct shape for each constant/variable/place holder  is difficult. 
I am trying to understand if there is a standard method which we can follow to do this.

Comment: Looks like this is a good start. http://briandolhansky.com/blog/2014/10/30/artificial-neural-networks-matrix-form-part-5